# NSNumber + a real number (e.g 50) = not possible?

Tags: iphone

i have an NSNumber that is taken from a string like this

```
NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

BRNumber = [f numberFromString:BRString];
```

of course this returns a value but now i wish to do something like

```
id y = BRNumber + 50;
```

It seems that this is not possible. So how should i go about doing this.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the raw integer before doing the computation, and wrap it back to an NSNumber afterwards.

```
NSNumber* y = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[BRNumber intValue] + 50];
```

If you're doing this a lot, you could create a category:

```
@implementation NSNumber (Arithmetics)
-(NSNumber*)numberByAddingInt:(int)val {
   return [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self intValue] + val];
}
@end
```

then you could use

```
NSNumber* y = [BRNumber numberByAddingInt:50];
```

There's no shorter ways, since ObjC doesn't have operator overloading.

Comment: ok great! it worked. Thanks alot. can only accept ur answer in 9 mins tho.